# How to make tkinter drop down to save data in python 3?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

How to make tkinter drop down to save data in python?
I want it to save data to variable 'sv' in the code.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import tkinter as tk

servs = ['Gmail', 'Yahoo', 'Comcast', 'Verizon', 'AT&T', 'Outlook']
sv = tk.StringVar()
drop = tk.OptionMenu(root, sv,*servs)
drop.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Comment: What's the problem/error you're getting here? That code should function exactly as you've specified

Comment: It is saving pyvar_0 to all options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to assign the value of selected option in dropdown. Use the option `command` when creating the dropdown. Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

servs = ['Gmail', 'Yahoo', 'Comcast', 'Verizon', 'AT&T', 'Outlook']
svar = tk.StringVar()
svar.set(servs[0])     #<-- Setting default item to servs's first item
sv = servs[0]          #<-- setting sv to default item
def _get(cur):         #<-- function to run
    sv = cur           #<-- 'cur' is the selected value

drop = tk.OptionMenu(root, svar, command = _get, *servs)
drop.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```